# Jenkins @Library resolution failing due to git.exe not existing, but where?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this command at the top of my pipeline file, and my build failed immediately in Jenkins while trying to resolve it:

```
@Library('MyLibrary') _

pipeline{
...
```

I also have this library setup in my global jenkins config.  Triple checked it.

The Jenkins log is below... the internet says this happens when git.exe is misconfigured or not found.  We have 100% verified git is installed on all the slaves.  However, I suspect that this failing git clone is running somewhere else since the pipeline has not officially started yet (we don't see RUNNING ON: blah in the log).

So... Does it run this on the master?  We have master set to 0 executors, and git is not installed there.

Is this problem solved as easily as installing git on the master?  Or is there some other magical place where these @Library includes get cloned?

Here is the Jenkins log output, with names changed to protect the innocent:

```
Started by user Me
15:28:23 Connecting to my github url
Obtained Jenkinsfile from blah
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Loading library MyLibrary@master
Examining <my github repo>
Attempting to resolve master as a branch
Resolved master as branch master at revision blah
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository <my repo url>.git
 > git init /home/afolder/jenkins/workspace/<git repo name>@libs/MyLibrary # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/afolder/jenkins/workspace/<git repo name>@libs/MyLibrary
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:813)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory 
"/home/afolder/jenkins/workspace/<git repo name>@libs/MyLibrary"): 
error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: yes, you neeed to configure git in master since Loading library MyLibrary@master happens in master, or try adding it in a node block I haven't tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default it will run on the Jenkins master.

Please follow the link for more [info](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54646).

You can read library file and give the file to [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) pipeline step

```
writeFile(file:"foo.groovy", text: libraryResource("bar.groovy"))
"groovy foo.groovy"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  (we don't have git on the master...)